# The series $\sum_{k=2}^N \frac{1}{\ln(k)}$ approaches $\frac{N}{\ln(N)}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

Show that, when $N \to \infty$: $$\sum_{k=2}^N \frac{1}{\ln(k)} \approx \frac{N}{\ln(N)}$$

I had already demonstrated that when $x\to\infty$, we have $\int_{2}^x\frac{dt}{\ln(t)} \approx \frac{x}{\ln(x)}$.
And I know that $\left(\int_{2}^x\frac{dt}{\ln(t)}\right)' = \frac{1}{\ln(x)}$. But I can't have more progress.

Comment: That's good already. Can you sandwich the sum between the corresponding integral plus/minus a constant?

Comment: the integral test criteria finishs it off quickly with the knowledge you already gained

Comment: For a more complete expansion, more than needed herein, apply the Euler-Maclarin Summation Formula.

Answer (score 2):

The function ${1\over \ln t}$ is decreasing on $[2, +\infty[$, therfore you have for $n \ge 3$ :

$$\int_n^{n+1} {dt \over\ln t} \le {1 \over \ln n} \le \int_{n-1}^{n} {dt \over\ln t}$$

Summing this you get 
$${n\over\ln n}\sim\int_3^{n+1} {dt \over\ln t} \le \sum_{k=3}^n{1 \over \ln k} \le \int_{2}^{n} {dt \over\ln t}\sim{n\over\ln n}$$

Answer (score 0):

Summation by parts gives

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{n=2}^{N}\frac{1}{\log(n)} &=& \frac{N-1}{\log N}-\sum_{n=2}^{N-1}(n-1)\left(\frac{1}{\log(n+1)}-\frac{1}{\log n}\right) \\&=&\frac{N}{\log N}+O(1)+\sum_{n=2}^{N-1}\frac{n\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\log(n)\log(n+1)}\end{eqnarray*}$$
and
$$ 0\leq\sum_{n=2}^{N-1}\frac{n\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\log(n)\log(n+1)}\leq \sum_{n=2}^{N-1}\frac{1}{\log(n)\log(n+1)}\ll\frac{N}{\log^2 N}. $$